# How to create a custom script with multiple commands in one line?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I want to create a script in git extensions with multiple git commands in one line.

Here is the sequence of commands I would like to execute :

```
fetch --all --prune & checkout -f -B master & reset --hard v2.10.0 & submodule foreach git fetch --all --prune & submodule update --init --recursive & submodule foreach git checkout -f -B master
```

How do I separate the arguments from each other to get this script working? At the moment I get the following error:

```
error: unknown switch `B'
usage: git fetch [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

Greetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to execute several commands in one go is :

```
sh -c "foo && bar && baz"

# check the docs for cmd.exe or powershell if you need to use one of these
# shells instead of 'sh'
```

Try to set :

- Command : `sh`
- Arguments : `-c "git fetch --all --prune && git checkout -f -B ..."`